# How to manage DB driver on Azure Function

Tags: node.js, azure, neo4j, azure-functions

I want to migrate my API server on VM to Azure function.

I use neo4j-drive on API server.

When API server starts:

```
const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password))
try {
    driver.verifyConnectivity()
    console.log('Driver created')
} catch (error) {
    console.log(`connectivity verification failed. ${error}`)
}
```

Before it exits:

```
process.on('exit', function() {
    driver.close();
    console.log('driver closed')
    console.log('exit');
});

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    console.log('SIGINT');
    process.exit();
});
```

On Azure function, where do I write them?

The following is a hello world example of azure function:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    if (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name)) {
        context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: "Hello " + (req.query.name || req.body.name)
        };
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the code before this:

```
context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
```

In that place, you can create the connection of the DB. And after you use it, you can close.

The content of `module.exports = async function (context, req){}` will run when you meet the trigger condition.